# react native ModuleResolver.resolveDependency error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

when i try to send my app to emulator, give this error. I cannot fix.

ModuleResolver.resolveDependency

DependencyGraph.resolveDependency

Object.resolve

Graph._resolveDependencies

Graph._processModule

How can i fix this problem.

Thanks.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

const App = () => {
  const [isCameraOpen, setIsCameraOpen] = useState(false);

  const startCamera = () => {
    setIsCameraOpen(true);
  };

  const takePhoto = async (camera) => {
    if (camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri); // Bu kısmı dilediğiniz gibi işleyebilirsiniz.
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isCameraOpen ? (
        <RNCamera
          style={styles.cameraPreview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          captureAudio={false}
        >
          {({ camera, status }) => {
            if (status !== 'READY') return <View />;
            return (
              <View style={styles.cameraControls}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => takePhoto(camera)} style={styles.captureButton}>
                  <Text style={styles.captureButtonText}>Capture</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        </RNCamera>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.startContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={startCamera} style={styles.startButton}>
            <Text style={styles.startButtonText}>Start Camera</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  startContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  startButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  startButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  cameraPreview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  cameraControls: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  captureButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 40,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
  captureButtonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});

export default App;
```

const App = () => {
6 |   const [isCameraOpen, setIsCameraOpen] = useState(false);
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\user\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:139:15)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\user\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:277:43)
at Object.resolve (C:\Users\user\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:169:21)
at Graph._resolveDependencies (C:\Users\user\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:473:35)
at Graph._processModule (C:\Users\user\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:261:38)
at async Graph._addDependency (C:\Users\user\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:372:20)
at async Promise.all (index 2)
at async Graph._processModule (C:\Users\user\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:322:5)
at async Graph._traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (C:\Users\user\AwesomeProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:249:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0)